# Get laravel current user on external php website

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-7

I have created an application with Laravel 7 that contains users that can log in.
In parallel, I create a showcase site for the application (another domain) and essentially html/css.
I would like on this showcase site to propose login and registration buttons if there is no user connected to the laravel.Otherwise I would just like to propose a "Dashboard" button if a user is connected to the Laravel application.

How to do that? I confess that I'm a bit lost. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an API on the laravel app which will be used by the "showcase site".

To login and authorize themselves you can use [JWT](https://jwt.io/)

to keep user data and use it on the showcase site you can either save them in

- **localstorage** *(just be careful not to save any sensitive data there as people can take that information in case of XSS vulnerable)*
- **indexdb**
- **cookies**

None of these methods are safe. They can be exploited using XSS so i advice on using JWT to secure sensitive data.

Comment: So I made an api (Laravel side) using Laravel Passport. My showcase site can connect to the api thanks to its client token.

I try to retrieve, via a webservice of my api, a cookie created in Laravel but I have an error. :`Undefined index: my_cookie_name` On the other hand localstorage and indexdb are client-side features. I don't see how to retrieve via the api a cookie. 
PS: I don't want my users to log in via the api, it's just the showcase site that wants to retrieve this data.